# Display uploaded data to MVC view and import selected record to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, postback

I need to import user uploaded CSV data to database.
Steps - 
1. User upload data to MVC View
2. Display all uploaded data in the View 
3. User can select the column name based on imported value
3. Import data based on user selection of the records.

To implement this, I created below Model -

```
public class ImportCSVData
{      
    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Names { get; set;}    // This is to display dynamic column      
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }     
    public DataTable Data { get; set; }  
}
```

In the controller, I am parsing the uploaded file (sample code)

```
    public ActionResult ImportCSVCustomer()
    {
        ImportCSVData model = new ImportCSVData();
        HttpPostedFileBase upfile = Request.Files["File"];
        model.File = upfile;            
            var dt = ParseCSVData(model);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {                 
                var dcRec = new DataColumn("ShouldImport", typeof(bool));                 
                dcRec.DefaultValue = false;
                dt.Columns.Add(dcRec);         
                model.Data = dt;
                List<SelectListItem> Names = getColumnNames();
                model.Names = Names;                 
                return PartialView("_ImportedCSVCustomer", model);
            }                      
        return View();
    }
```

Sample View that I designed -

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
   <tr>
    <td data-val="@i">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sid" value=@Model.Data.Rows[i][Model.Data.Columns.Count - 1] class="sid">
   </td>
    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Data.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
     <td>
         @Model.Data.Rows[i][j].ToString()
         @Html.HiddenFor(Model.Data.Rows[i][j].ToString())
     </td>
     }
   </tr>
   }
```

I was working on the view to display, but , unable to get the model value after posting from View to Controller.
Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Nothing in your code makes any sense. Is that a GET or POST method? And you don't use `DataTable` (you cannot post that). You need a view model with properties to display/submit your data

Comment: what is the best option to design model with properties which will behave as like data table? Because my columns and rows both can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the model in the return statement. So you need:

`return View(model)`

Then in the view you have to make sure you are implementing that view by having at the top of the .cshtml file

`@model xxx.ImportCSVData`

Where `xxx` is the namespace.

In all honest, I'd also put `[HttpPost]` on top of the controller as well to make sure you can only POST to it and I'd use the AntiForgeryToken. http://peterkellner.net/2014/05/19/asp-net-mvc-forms-need-include-html-antiforgerytoken-security/

Comment: In my get method, I am returning model, also I am using model in my view with proper name space. That's why I am able to display data in the grid but cannot post to controller.

Comment: You should have two separate controllers. One for the GET and one for the POST. And the difference between them is that you will be passing in data.

```[HttpPost]```
```public ActionResult ImportCSVCustomer(ImportCSVData model)```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion. I have used two separate controller only. But I have not given code of the 2nd controller where I am posting data from the view as I am having difficulty to access model value and I am stuck there only!!